# modified files on boot partition being reset after first boot

Tags: boot, sd-card, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, filesystem

I am trying to perform a headless setup of a raspberry pi zero W, which involves creating some new files in the boot partition of the SD card before putting it into the pi (wpa_supplicant.conf and ssh).
I flashed the card, added the files, and verified that they were saved by ejecting the card then putting it back into my pc to check. However, when I insert the card into the raspberry pi and power it up, it does not connect to Wifi, and when I shut it down and put the card back into my computer, I find that the files that I added are gone.

I followed the same steps as multiple guides on the Internet and none of them seemed to mention how to get around this problem. I am using the latest version of Raspbian stretch lite, a Unirex MicroSDHC 8GB Class 10 card, and a Raspberry Pi zero W. I have tried multiple sd cards, pis and host PCs, but i have not been able to try any different models of anything yet.

Does anybody know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour  May I suggest that we need a little more help in trying to give a good answer here.  "multiple guides" are mentioned but without knowing how to find them to check your work it is difficult.

Comment: Have set the country code in `wpa_supplicant.conf`? Without it wifi will not start.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

The files are copied to the default locations on boot, then deleted.

If they don't work there is something else wrong.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 0):

Milliways is correct. The changes made in the boot folder files gets copied to the correct locations. I found it easiest to just edit the wpa_suplicant.conf file directly in the etc/wpa_suplicant directory to get it to connect to WiFi.